# How to remove forward slash which gets to the filepath field while acessing json data

Tags: php, android, json, special-characters

[Screenshot of path stored in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTOSj.png)

[Json data which I retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuonm.png)

PHP code which I used to encode JSON:

```
<?php
$host='localhost'; $username=''; $pwd=''; $db="";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');

if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
    echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM qtb";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

if($result) 
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))     
    {
        $data[]=$row;   
    }       

    print(json_encode(array('QOB' => $data))); 
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: For clarity - do you want the "Qp" value to be 'bb.jpg' or '/bb.jpg' or '\bb.jpg'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you actually meant backward slash in your question - see comment.

Try using the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES option in the json_encode:

```
json_encode(array('QOB' => $data), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

The backward slash ('\') is escaping the forward slash ('/') - so if you really wanted the forward slash removed (as the title states) then your paths would not be correct.  If you really mean 'replace the forward slash with backward slash' then that is different.

To change the forward slash to a backward slash

```
print(str_replace('/', '\\', json_encode(array('QOB' => $data), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)));
```

Sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/babf45f149226518a796714323dbff6040664a9b

Comment: json_encode(array('QOB' => $data), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)  worked perfectly as needed..  Thanks :)